# PHP - iCal description in iOS

Tags: php, ios, icalendar

I've read that if iOS determines the iCal description field to be an address it will allow it to click through to the maps app. 
I've got an iCal feed that I created, I'm sending 'town, postcode' to it but it's not clickable in my iPhone calendar.

What is the criteria that iOS uses to determine that an address is in the description field?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the LOCATION property instead. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.7

Comment: It's more from an iOS point of view than iCal - I've got town/postcode in the location and description field but iOS isn't recognising an address. I wondering if there is a specific format that iOS recognises? ....maybe if I also had a house/building number....I'm currently not capturing house numbers so I would have to look them all up to add them in.